# regular expression to capture content of "..."

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract the characters between first two occurrences of `"` in my string.

example:

```
my $string = 's.w;;wq[]][.zaw"this is what I need"as.w;;wq[]][.zaw"this I do not need".w;;wq[]][.za';
```

Thanks in advance for solving my problem :)

Comment: This is not a coding service; what have you tried? __update__: oh, apparently this IS a coding service <_< @miller

Comment: It's going to be fairly difficult to find characters between the first occurrence of `.`, unless they are zero-width characters.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I think OP means first quote-pair.

Comment: you example doesn't really make sense. so you want `w;;wq[]][`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because is is a `gimme ze code` question.

Comment: @Mathletics You are correct that SO is not a coding service, and kudos for trying to educate the new user about proper usage of SO.  Most times, I would do the same.  However, when the answer includes just a single regex topic, I will sometimes just provide that documentation link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [perlretut - Using Character Classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes).

As demonstrated:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = q{s.w;;wq[]][.zaw"this is what I need"as.w;;wq[]][.zaw"this I do not need".w;;wq[]][.za};

if ( $string =~ /"([^"]*)/ ) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
this is what I need
```

Or just use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
my $desire = ( split /"/, $string )[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is: `/"([^"]*)"/`:

```
my ($wanted_string) = $string =~ /"([^"]*)"/;
```